# What is the meaning of "to perform sexually"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of "to perform sexually" in this sentence

---

From serie 'Friends'

> "Ever since she left me, I haven't been able **to perform sexually**"

Comment: _to have sex_ I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it means "I haven't been able to have sex."

Depending on the context, it can mean emotionally, or physically.

In the emotional sense, the person may not be of a state of mind where they are interested in sex. In the more physical sense of the expression the person may not be able to physically become aroused. The latter often applies to men more than to women (which if memory of that episode of 'Friends' serves, is the case here).